# Android recyclerView data binding adapter data

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I am implementing a `Recycler View` and its respective `adapter` using `Android Data Binding`. The problem is that in all the tutorials I have seen, they initialize the data of the adapter with a `Collection` of `View model` class, like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<ViewModel> items;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<ViewModel> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

.....
}
```

But the data I want to pass to the `Recycler View` is a `Collection` of `records` from my `database`:

```
private ArrayList<Record> items;
```

How can I do that??

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

**li_item.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="report"
        type="viewmodel.ReportVM"/>
</data>

....

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_report_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:text="@{report.name}"
        tools:text="Report 1"
        />

....
```

**ADAPTER**

```
    public class ReportRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportRVAdapter.ReportViewHolder> {

private List<ReportDb> data;


public ReportRVAdapter(final List<ReportDb> reportData) {
    this.data = reportData;
}

@Override
public ReportRVAdapter.ReportViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.li_item, parent, false);
    return new ReportViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ReportViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ReportDb item = data.get(position);

    holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.name, item.getName());
    holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.contractor, item.getContractor());

    //make binding happen immediately
    holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
}


public class ReportViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ViewDataBinding binding;

    public ReportViewHolder(final View rowView) {
        super(rowView);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rowView);
    }

    public ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
        return binding;
    }
}
}
```

**MODEL VIEW**

```
public class ReportVM extends BaseObservable {

public String name;
public String contractor;

public ReportVM() {
}

@Bindable
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Bindable
public String getContractor() {
    return contractor;
}

public void setContractor(final String contractor) {
    this.contractor = contractor;
}
}
```

Comment: how do you retract data from your `Record`?

Comment: I do a query to the database

Comment: It won't be efficient to do it inside `onBindViewHolder`, so you should pre-read data from database into mdoel I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any collection in RecyclerView, It depends on you how you bind value with the View(TextView, ImageView).
Example:-

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // - get element from your dataset at this position
            // - replace the contents of the view with that element
            final String name = mDataset.get(position);
            holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
}
```

in above example, it depends on you, if you use Map then you need to get value using key. For set same get method can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did realized that instead of:

```
holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.name, item.getName());
holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.contractor, item.getContractor());

//make binding happen immediately
holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
```

I should write this:

```
holder.getBinding().setReport(new ReportVM(item));
```

and my POJO:

```
private ReportDb report;

public ReportVM(final ReportDb report) {
    this.report = report;
}

public String getName() {
    return report.getName();
}

public String getContractor() {
    return report.getContractor();
}
```